# WordPress error_log filling up with SQL errors

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

Should I create this table or it could be an error fixable in some other way?
Every time I search a customer number I get one of these errors in error_log within the WordPress document root.
I need some help in debugging this please I am in panic mode:

```
[16-Dec-2022 14:12:35 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'store_wp557.wp_wc_customer_lookup' doesn't exist for query SELECT SUM(wps.total_sales) 
                            FROM `wp_wc_customer_lookup` AS wpl 
                            JOIN `wp_wc_order_stats` as wps ON wpl.customer_id = wps. customer_id 
                            WHERE wpl.user_id=122442
         made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Form_Handler::process_login, wp_signon, do_action('wp_login'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, XLWCTY_Common::update_user_order_count, XLWCTY_Common::get_customer_total_spent
```

Comment: check with phpmyadmin if wp_wc_customer_lookup exists

Comment: This is a WooCommerce table that's missing. It's a miracle your shop works at all. WooCommerce has a decent support team. Ask them?

Comment: Thank you I was unsure of where to ask my apologies if this was the wrong place!

Should I delete this post since I've posted on wordpress support forums you think?

Comment: Leave your question, please. If you figure out the answer, come on here and answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the **WooCommerce -> Status -> Tools** page in the backend then you'll find the **Verify base database tables** tool.

Click on the **Verify database** button it will validate and recreate the missing base tables of WooCommerce.

You'll also see the **Update database** tool click the **Update database** button and all the databases will be updated to the latest version of WooCommerce.

**Note: Make sure you have a full backup of the site and database before running those tools. otherwise, you might lose the data if something goes wrong.**